# THE LINE OFTHE MOONLIGHT IS NOT STRAIGHT ANYMORE

Tags: earth, moon

I am from the USA, just a retired soldier who looks at the sky a lot. This morning 26 SEP 2020 at 1am, the Moon was approximately a quarter Moon. It was bright, the line/shadow on the moon was not straight. I have never in my 58 years saw any Moon that appeared this way. The line of the light on the moon is always a  straight line. This morning it had a weird bend in the middle outward. It looked like the Sun was presenting light around the Earth with something new obstructing the light in the middle projecting  outward. If you no soldier speak and are great with numbers, you will understand I don't want to play numbers. Just want to know what else is in our neighborhood or what has changed in the position of the moon and earth? Hope this site is still active and God Bless All. Thanks! PS please do not insult my intelligence and say this has always occurred.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PSE. The line that seperates the dark side from the light side is curved. Sorry if this “insults your intelligence” but this is objectively true. However there may be certain conditions where every now and then it may be straight (I saw this in a perfect half moon).

Comment: That is, it may appear straight.

Comment: Why do you think this site is not active?

Comment: I am a little surprised that this has attracted so many downvotes but no one seems to have posted a comment explaining why they downvoted.  There are no close votes so it presumably is not any of the usual close reasons.  The OP certainly cannot fix whatever problem you think is there until they are told what it is, so while you certainly don't have to explain downvotes on SE, it might help the OP, a new member, if at least one downvoter explained their issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I include pictures from moon phases, you find them in the Internet quiet[image] easily, so one has almost straight lines only at half moon. Perhaps you tell us which picture is the one you saw? Or draw a sketch yourself? From your question it is hard to imagine what you saw different from other times.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the comments and I do owe an explanation. First my phone camera can never take a clear picture of the moon. I will get a camera that will. I thought the site was inactive because while looking through it, many of the posts and replies are years old. Thanks for the moderate comments. The pictures only confirmed what I said. All the pictures show non straight lines and views I have seen before. Last morning, the view I saw was Bright, and it had clear simetry of light and dark. The pictures posted also do not show the crisp exagorated middle pushed out. All comments are appreciated and this seems like a friendly community to newbies.